# Как поделить элементы списка друг на друга?

Tags: python, list

Условно, у меня есть список `[5, 7, 9, 14]`. Каждый раз количество и сами элементы меняются. Как с помощью цикла for сделать так, чтобы элементы поделились друг на друга? `(5/7/9/14=0.0566...)`
Если с помощью цикла for не получается, то как в целом возможно это сделать?

Comment: В чём конкретно у вас возникли трудности? Питон позволяет довольно легко пройти по всем элементам массива в цикле **for**. Внутри массива вы уже должны работать с делением и записывать значение в переменную типа **float**, которую надо объявить перед циклом

Comment: Если в списке окажется 0, что делать?

Comment: `a[0] / math.prod(a[1:])`.

Comment: `functools.reduce(operator.truediv, a)`.

Comment: @Oopss - oopss!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Если с помощью цикла for не получается, ...

Получается :-) :

```
lst = [5, 7, 9, 14]

result = lst[0]                      # делимое

for element in lst[1:]:              
    result /= element                # то же самое, как result = result / element

print(result)                        # тест
```

*Вывод:*

> ```
> 0.005668934240362812
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

`lst[1:]` есть список элементов из списка `lst` за исключением первого элемента.
Этими элементами — делителями — постепенно делим в цикле первый элемент списка `lst` — делимое.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Отличный легкий способ. Я еще только начинаю изучать питон, так что  пока что нет никакого опыта или фантазии. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @drsp3ed, не стоит. Когда был мой ответ для вас полезным, вы можете голосовать за него (клик на треугольник вверх у его начала) и / или принять его (клик на галочку).

Answer (score 1):

Без цикла - с применением стандартных модулей `itertools` и `operator`:

```
from itertools import accumulate           # постепенное применение операции
from operator import itruediv              # обычное деление, напр. itruediv(3, 2) == 1.5

lst = [36, 2, 3, 4]

all_quotiеnts = accumulate(lst, itruediv)  # все промежуточные результаты делении
results = list(all_quotiеnts)              # перевод итератора в список
result = results[-1]                       # последний элемент - финальный результат

print(results)                             # промежуточные результаты (только для понятия)
print(result)
```

> ```
> [36, 18.0, 6.0, 1.5]
> 1.5
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать с функцией `reduce()` и лямбдой:

```
from functools import reduce

l = [5, 7, 9, 14]

print(reduce(lambda a, b : a / b, l))
```